# validar campos de formulario de login e redirecionar

Tags: wordpress

olá eu tenho um formulario de login popup, mas esse eu fiz div por div sem plugin nenhum, porém agora preciso validas os campos de usuario e senha e depois redirecionar para uma pagina externa, e como eu fiz sem plugin não sei como vou fazer para validar o formulario.

a pergunta é :  TEM ALGUM PLUGIN QUE FAÇA A ASSOCIAÇÃO DESTE FORMULÁRIO DE LOGIN COM O BANCO DE DADOS SEM PRECISAR QUE EU FAÇO ESSE PROCESSO TODO / AGRADEÇO DESDE JÁ!

Comment: Vc quer efetuar de fato o login do usuário no WordPress quando o form for submetido OU quer apenas validar se usuário e senha estão ok e depois encaminhá-lo para outra página? Pergunto porque vc disse que quer redirecionar para uma página "externa"... isso quer dizer que o usuário precisa estar logado ou não? O que vc quis dizer com "página externa"?

Answer (score 0):

o site leva leva para uma plataforma em outro site, queria que ao fazer login encaminhasse para esse site para poder fazer o acesso, porém eu conseguir fazer isso usando o login do propio wordpress e cooloquei para que os usuarios que entrassem com a senha de assinante fosse direcionado para essa pagina... e depois me veio a seguinte questão : " eu posso usar o login existente na outra pagina  no meu site ?" pox exemplo: na outro site tem uma tela de login para entrar na plataforma, e no meu site tem um longin que leva para esse outro login.